# How do you have logical or in case part of switch statment?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, logical-operators

If you have a switch statement and want certain code to be run when the value is one value *or* another how do you do it? The following code always goes to the default case.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    switch(x)
    {
        case 5 || 2:
            cout << "here I am" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "no go" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
switch (x)
{
case 5:
case 2:
    cout << "here I am" << endl;
    break;
}
```

Known as "falling through".

Just to point out that the reason the `default` case is executed in the posted code is that the result of `5 || 2` is `1` (`true`). If you set `x` to `1` in the posted code the `5 || 2` case would be executed (see http://ideone.com/zOI8Z).

Comment: @Celeritas, I never said it evaluates to `2` and it is logical OR.

Comment: Sorry I meant 5 || 2 evaluates to 1. But in binary 101 OR 11 = 111 which is 7, not 1. Right?

Comment: @Celeritas, it is _logical_ OR, not bitwise. Check out the link in my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Make it fall through:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    switch(x)
    {
        case 5:
        // there's no break statement here,
        // so we fall through to 2
        case 2:
            cout << "here I am" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "no go" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`5 || 2`, by the way, evaluates to 1 (or `true`, as it is a logical expression), you can try it.

Answer (score 4):

Let the `switch` **fall-through**:

```
switch(x)
{
    case 2:
    case 5:
        cout << "here I am" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "no go" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case2:
case5:
   //do things
   break;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a really good read](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/programming/c/keyword-switch-case-default) about switch/case and their slight difference between C/C++ and some other information about labels (ABCD:) you might like to know.